# Table rates for each fixed items at a fixed shipping cost for Magento 1.8?

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, table-rates

How can I do a table rate for each fixed items at a fixed shipping cost?

For instance, I want to charge **25€ per 6 bottles** of wine, how do I do this in my `tablerates.csv`

```
Country Region/State    Zip/Postal Code #of Items (and above)   Shipping Price
FRA         *           *               1                       25
FRA         *           *               6                       50
FRA         *           *               12                      75
```

What I do right now is just keep adding the numbers of item and price **manually**, is there any way to **do it better**?

Answer (score 2):

You could write a custom carrier that allowed you to enter an extra field in here to store the qty multiplier. Then just take the table rates implementation and extend it to have that custom column and do the work.

There are extensions out there that do this, we implement at WebShopApps with an algorithm column, in this scenario would be set to i=6@25, just 1 row in the csv.